# ListView inside Stack Inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, listview, stack, singlechildscrollview

I need to scroll the whole screen, i am using (single child scroll view => stack => ListView.builder). but there is no scrolling. however i am using:

> shrinkWrap: true,
> physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

**The Code Is:**

```
return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.red,height: 300,),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: screen.isPhone ? 150 : 240,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 20,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                            ProductItemWidget(showDeleteIconButton: true),
                      ),
                    ),
                   Text("HEY"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics and changing is to Bouncing instead?

Comment: Main thing is to  replacing LayoutBuilder  with SafeArea(for device paddings) and use single child scroll only. After safearea you don't have to use that Containers margin given that you're using it to avoid the device edges. And why listview inside card? Do you need separate scroll behavior inside cards too? If not use map() instead.

Answer (score 0):

remove  height: constraints.maxHeight,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).